# Specifying serialized names in java class for firestore document

Tags: firebase, serialization, google-cloud-firestore, proguard

I am trying to store a `document` in firestore in my android app using a [custom object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects). If I am using proguard for building my app, is there a way to specify the serialized name for the fields inside my class like the way `Gson` provides using `@SerializedName` annotation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can specify the name a Java property gets in the JSON of the document with the [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) annotation. For example:

```java
public class Data {
    @PropertyName("some_field_name")
    public String someFieldName;
}
```

If you use getters and setters (instead of using a public field as above), be sure to put the annotation on both getter and setter:

```java
public class Data {
    private String someFieldName;

    @PropertyName("some_field_name")
    public String getSomeFieldName() { return someFieldName; }

    @PropertyName("some_field_name")
    public void setSomeFieldName(String someFieldName) { this.someFieldName = someFieldName; }
}
```

This annotation is shared between Cloud Firestore and the older Firebase Realtime Database, so I recommend also checking out some of the [previous questions about `PropertyName`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%20propertyname), such as [Naming convention with Firebase serialization/deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690641/naming-convention-with-firebase-serialization-deserialization/40732585#40732585).

Comment: What if I need the same functionality when saving data into firestore. My field name in java is called `xyzSomethings`. But I want it to be saved as `somethings`. Is there a way?

Comment: The exact same annotation exists for Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this. This doesn't work. It works when reading value from firestore. not when saving data into firestore

Comment: In that case, please open a new question with the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The issue is `@PropertyName` on provate fields doesn't work. It works when putting the annotation on public getters and setters. This question has some info on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work. Thanks