# App crashes when trying to enter onDataChange Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show me all the users from firebase databse in a cardview who is in a recyclerview but in debugger shows me an error at line 60 in UserActivity.
I put a screenshot with my database:
[image]

The UsersFragment:

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_users3, container, false );
recyclerView=view.findViewById (R.id.recycler_view  );

recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( getContext () ) );
mUsers=new ArrayList<> (  );
readUsers();

        return view;
    }

    private void readUsers () {
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance ().getCurrentUser ();
        DatabaseReference referenc= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users");

        referenc.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear ();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren ()){
                    User user=snapshot.getValue (User.class);
                    assert user!=null;
                    assert firebaseUser!=null;
                    if(!firebaseUser.getUid ().equals ( user.getUid () )){
                        mUsers.add ( user );

                    }
                }
                userAdapter=new UserAdapter ( getContext (),mUsers );
                recyclerView.setAdapter ( userAdapter );
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }


}
```

The UserAdapter.In i used the User class:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    public UserAdapter(Context mContext,List<User> mUsers){
        this.mUsers=mUsers;
        this.mContext=mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from ( mContext ).inflate ( R.layout.users_template ,parent,false);

        return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder ( view );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
User user=mUsers.get ( position );
holder.username.setText ( user.getFirstName () );

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return mUsers.size ();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView username;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            username=itemView.findViewById ( R.id.username1 );
        }

    }
}
```

The User that stores the FirstName :

```
public class User {
   public String firstName;
    public String secondName;
    public String uid;
    public String email;
    public User(){

    }



    public User (String firstName, String secondName, String uid, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.uid=uid;
        this.email=email;
    }

    public User (String firstname, String secondname) {
    }
@PropertyName ( "FirsName" )
    public String getFirstName () {
        return firstName;
    }
    @PropertyName ("SecondName" )
    public String getSecondName () {
        return secondName;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "Uid" )
    public String getUid () {
        return uid;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "E-mail" )
    public String getEmail () {
        return email;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "FirsName" )
    public void setFirstName (String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "SecondName" )
    public void setSecondName (String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "Uid" )
    public void setUid (String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "E-mail" )
    public void setEmail (String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The rules for my database are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
      ".write":"true",
    "users":{
    "$user_id":{
       ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id",
       ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"

    }
  }
}
}
```

In the debug mode it shows me this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sportsbuddy, PID: 662
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: secondname
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.addProperty(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:540)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:471)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:312)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:413)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:212)
        at com.example.sportsbuddy.Fragments.UsersFragment$1.onDataChange(UsersFragment.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

The main error is at onDataChange in UsersFragment.

I expect to show me all the users that I have in the database.

Comment: You have to post complete error that you're  getting and not only one line of error.

Comment: I modified now.Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your error says:

```
Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: secondname
```

For understanding what this error means, you need to understand how Firebase serializes & deserializes the data that you receive from your database.

Firebase uses field names, as well as getters and setters to serialize and deserialize object, which means, whenever you receive JSON object from your database, firebase will map these key values with your getters/setters as well as the fields in your POJO class.

To remove this error, you'll have to either change your field names, i.e.

```
public String secondName;
```

to something different than that you have in your database, **OR** , you need to change the getter & setter function names. Error is given as firebase is seeing the property twice, once in your fields, and second time in your getter/setter.

Also, try making your variables private. It might help. Also, how about changing "E-mail" in your database to simply "email"?

Comment: I changed the fields in my database but still shows me that I have an error at onDataChange.

Comment: What error are you getting? It'll be a different error this time, might have something to do with "E-mail". possibly NullPointerException

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: secondname

Comment: This error still appears and i modified the text in the database

Comment: Check case sensitivity of your fields.

Comment: What change did you make? Did you make your secondName to something different than your database like mSecondName?

Comment: Yes.I changed secondName from my database in SECONDNAME

Comment: You dont have to change it in database. You have to change it in your POJO class. Make it different than what you have in your database. Something like mSecondName or something!

Comment: I understand now.I'll do that.Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I'll not forget.

Comment: Hello!I have a new problem.The cardview for every user appears but appears empty.Can you look over again in my code and found the problem.The debugger says: "W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for FIRST NAME found on class com.example.sportsbuddy.User"

Comment: all your errors are self explanatory. Read the errors and see what it's saying. It is saying there's no setter method, or field inside the "User" class. Read my answer properly and you'll get answer to all your questions

Comment: Sorry.I was on a rush and i didn't think when I asked the question.Found it myself after posting the comment.The only problem that I have Righ not is that appears my name,not for other user.

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing the exact error would be difficult to say.

But i think is when you convert the firebase object to user class. In your firebase the field email is"e-mail" and in your class is "email". Change it to match your firebase database or the reverse (change the firebase field to match your user class).

Post your complete error in order for us to be able to provide more information.

---Edit---

Its the case sensitivity between the firebase database and your user class. Change the fields to match each other and you will be fine.

Comment: In the debugger mode it show me an error at UsersFragment at onDataChange

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor from

```js
    public User (String firstname, String secondname) {
    }
```

to

```js
    public User (String firstName, String secondName) {
    }
```

Also, your firebase key doesn't match with your model class key.

Your FirebaseKey is `FirstName` and your model class key is `firstName`. Fix this(same for `SecondName` vs `secondName`)!

Comment: @SagarBalyan it is still wrong because that error is completely different

Answer (score 0):

Both your fields and your getters/setters are public. This means that Firebase sees two properties:

```
secondname for the field
SecondName for the getter/setter
```

Since it's now unclear how to map the Java class to the JSON from the database, it throws this error:

> Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property

The simplest fix is to make your fields private:

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private String uid;
    private String email;

    public User(){
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I also updated my answer to your previous question to reflect this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809841/list-of-users-is-empty/56812042?noredirect=1#comment100186458_56812042

Comment: Note that Alex Mamo left a comment about the public field names at your question about the same problem six days ago already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816574/app-crashes-when-trying-to-enter-ondatachange-firebase-android/56817562#56817562. Please limit yourself to a single post per problem, and follow up when people ask questions and try to help you.