# Why i cant store info from my firestore to my java model class

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

Store Activity Class is supposed to retrieve the data from the database and send it the Store Model Class as well as set up a recycler view to display information. There is also a Store Adapter class which handles to the individual items of the Recycler View, it retrieves the information it needs from the Store Model Class.

Whilst it does seem to retrieve data from the database, it does not seem to send that data to the model class. We believe this issue is occurring in the Store Activity Class and have noted in the comments where we think the issue is happening.

This is the structure of the Firestore Database, all of the fields in Store are String:
[image: 1]

This what the app displays currently
[image: This what the app displays currently.]

the code involved

```
package com.example.deliveryapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;


public class StoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    //Gets the current instance of the database
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    //Stores the Collection Path for Store
    private CollectionReference StoreRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("Store");
    //Variable for storing the RecyclerView
    private RecyclerView sFirestoreList;
    StoreAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stores);

        //Gets Current Instance of Database
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        StoreRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("Store");
        sFirestoreList = findViewById(R.id.StoreList_rv);

        sFirestoreList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //Creates the Query for getting information from the Database
        Query query = StoreRef;

        //Sends the Query to the Database and send that information to the Model Class
        //reminder to self the problem is in this part (Possibly), the app is retrieving data from the Database however can't seem to send it to the model class
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<StoreModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<StoreModel>()
                .setQuery(query, StoreModel.class)
                .build();

        //Connects the activity to the Adapter Class
        adapter = new StoreAdapter(options);
        //Connects the RecyclerView to the Adapter Class
        sFirestoreList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Gets the App to start reading data from the Database
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    // Gets the App to Stop reading data from the Database
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}



package com.example.deliveryapp;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

public class StoreAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<StoreModel, StoreAdapter.StoreViewholder> {

    public StoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<StoreModel> options){
        super(options);
    }

    //Binds the data from the model class to Adapter's variables
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StoreViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull StoreModel model){
        holder.storeName.setText(model.getStoreName());
        holder.storeAddress.setText(model.getStoreAddress());
        holder.storeID.setText(model.getStoreID());
        //holder.storeID.setText("Test ID");
        //holder.storeName.setText("Test Store");
        //holder.storeAddress.setText("Test Address");
    }

    //Finds the display card for the data to be printed on
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StoreViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.storelist, parent, false);
        return new StoreAdapter.StoreViewholder(view);
    }

    //Prints the Store Information to the Activity Display
    class StoreViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView storeID, storeName, storeAddress;
        //Finds the Textviews by their ID and sets the their text
        public StoreViewholder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            storeID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Store_ID);
            storeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Store_Name);
            storeAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Store_Address);
        }
    }
}


package com.example.deliveryapp;

public class StoreModel {
    private String storeID;
    private String storeName;
    private String storeAddress;

    //private String storeID = "TestID";
    //private String storeName = "TestName";
    //private String storeAddress = "TestAddress";

    //Empty Constructore for Firebase
    public StoreModel(){
        //Empty
    }

    //Constructor for gathering information from the firestore
    public StoreModel(String StoreAddress, String StoreID, String StoreName) {
        this.storeID = StoreID;
        this.storeName = StoreName;
        this.storeAddress = StoreAddress;
    }

    // Gets the Store ID
    public String getStoreID() {
        return storeID;
    }

    // Sets the Store ID
    public void setStoreID(String StoreID) {
        this.storeID = StoreID;
    }

    // Gets the Store Name
    public String getStoreName() {
        return storeName;
    }

    // Sets the Store Name
    public void setStoreName(String StoreName) {
        this.storeName = StoreName;
    }

    // Gets the Store Address
    public String getStoreAddress() {
        return storeAddress;
    }

    // Sets the Store Address
    public void setStoreAddress(String StoreAddress) {
        this.storeAddress = StoreAddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase/Firestore uses JavaBean naming convention to determine the mapping between the Java fields and the fields in the document.

This means that your `public String getStoreID()` method gets interpreted as a `storeID` field in the document. But wht you actually have in your document is `StoreID`, with an uppercase `S`. Since `storeID` and `StoreID` are not exactly the same, Firebase doesn't map them when reading/writing data.

You can either user `storeID` as the field name in your document, or use a [`PropertyName` annotation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) on each of the getters and settings:

```
@PropertyName("StoreID")
public String getStoreID() {
    return storeID;
}

@PropertyName("StoreID")
public void setStoreID(String StoreID) {
    this.storeID = StoreID;
}
```

Also see:

- [Specifying serialized names in java class for firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417744/specifying-serialized-names-in-java-class-for-firestore-document)